# Package not found on virtualenv - No module named "mypack"

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools

Hi !

I've tried to use a package I've created (named `mypackage`) on my main program (named `collector`). `mypackage` is defined with the `setup.py` below:

```
name = "mypackage"
[...]
packages = find_packages(),
include_package_data = True,
exclude_package_data = { '': ['README.md'] }
[...]
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
        'my-package=mypack.mypack:main'
    ]
},
```

I want to use a little program present this package, which will normally be called as below on `collector`:

```
from mypack.common.prog import mylittleprogram
```

I've tried to install `mypackage` on a virtualenv, and then (re)installed my main program. Then I executed it, and there is the error I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
from project.common.collector import collectArt
File "/root/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/collector-0.1-py3.5.egg/project/common/collector.py", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mypack'
```

Also, when the virtualenv is activated, I've just tried to launch the entry-point named `my-package`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/project/bin/my-package", line 11, in <module>
load_entry_point('mypackage==0.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'my-package')()
File "/root/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 560, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
File "/root/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2648, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/root/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2302, in load
return self.resolve()
File "/root/project/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2308, in resolve
module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'mypack'
```

Note 1: I precise that I have the `__init__.py` on each folder of my package.

Note 2: the `virtualenv` folders are on the same folder as my main program.

How do I use `mylittleprogram` present on `mypackage` on my `collector` main program with `virtualenv` ? Did I made something wrong ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the issue, I had to install my package via the following command:

```
python setup.py develop
```

And then the package is recognized. This command has to be executed when the virtualenv is activated, and be executed on the directory of the package.

Hope this will help someone in the future !